# Linear forms and the first isomorphism theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$, $f:V \rightarrow F$ a linear form on $V$, and $N$ the kernel of $f$. Prove that if $f$ is not identically zero, then $V/N$  is isomorphic to  F. I am having difficulty with surjectivity. Any hints appreciated.

Edit: There is a hint that I do not understand the notation for. It states to evaluate $f$ at $(c/f(x))z$. Which I am not sure what that means.

Comment: The image of $f$ is a subspace of $F$. What is the dimension of $F$?

Comment: @Bungo the question does not state the dimension of $F$.

Comment: If we consider a field as a vector space over itself, its dimension is $1$. So, if the image of $f$ is not $\{0\}$ then it must be all of $F$.

Comment: @Bungo ah yes by rank nullity. Ok thanks.

Comment: It's even simpler than rank nullity (which only applies if $V$ is finite dimensional). The image of any linear map is a subspace of the target vector space. Since $F$ has dimension $1$, the only possible subspaces of $F$ are $\{0\}$ (which has dimension $0$) and $F$ (which has dimension $1$). So the image of $f$ is either $\{0\}$ or $F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By hypothesis, there exists $v\in V$ such that $f(v)\neq 0$. Since $F$ is a field, $f(v)$ is invertible, i.e., there is $\alpha\in F$ such that $\alpha f(v)=1$. So, for all $x\in F$, we have $$f(x\alpha v)=x(\alpha f(v))=x.$$